# How to make a shared legend across multiple pie charts in a map using amcharts 4?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have a map that is based on [this](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-dynamic-pie-charts/) example from the amCharts website. I want to add a clickable shared legend across these pie charts. So that whenever someone clicks a legend element, it updates all the pie charts to show only "active" slice values. I have tried to create a custom legend in this way:

```
// Setting up legend
var legend = new am4maps.Legend();
legend.parent = chart.chartContainer;
legend.background.fill = am4core.color("#000");
legend.background.fillOpacity = 0.05;
legend.y = am4core.percent(100);
legend.verticalCenter = "bottom";
legend.padding(10,15,10,15)
legend.data = [{
    "name": "Category #1",
    "fill": chart.colors.getIndex(0)
}, {
    "name": "Category #2",
    "fill": chart.colors.getIndex(1)
}, {
    "name": "Category #3",
    "fill": chart.colors.getIndex(2)
}, {
    "name": "Category #4",
    "fill": chart.colors.getIndex(2)
}];

// Does something when legend marker is clicked
legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
    var index = ev.target.dataItem.index;
    if (ev.target.isActive) { 
        //????.hide();
    }
    else {
        //????.show();
    }
})
```

In this example ([codepen](https://codepen.io/fauchald1/pen/ywNXab?&editable=true)) I create a custom legend and a function which triggers when legend markers are 'hit'. I have tried many different things in this function, but have not gotten far. I simply don't know how to access the different slice elements (indicated with '????') of the charts for manipulation on legend marker 'hit'.

Another possible route I have seen is to plug it directly into the chart in some way. But this only seems to work for single pie charts. (Shown [here](https://codepen.io/fauchald1/pen/aMOWay?&editable=true)) This example also shows exactly the kind of behaviour I want. Problem is that I want ONE legend, not one for every pie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your first approach, using a custom legend.

You can use the hidden property on your chart to hide specific categories.

```
pieSeriesTemplate.dataFields.hidden = "hidden";
```

You can now add an event to toggle this property on all pie chart data. Use the `"up"` event, because `event.target.isActive` is updated after the `"hit"` event is called.

```
legend.itemContainers.template.events.on("up", (ev) => {
  var category = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.name;
  pieSeries.data.forEach(item => item.pieData.find(i => i.category === category).hidden = !ev.target.isActive);
  pieSeries.validateData();
});
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZdxvL) I forked and updated your code pen. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly when scaled up as well, but I will try to find a more efficient solution for finding the right data points. I also noticed that the map seems to jump around a bit when pieSeries.validateData() is called.